# react native expo how to require an image?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm learning react native expo

I want to require an image from assets/images

[image]

The image I want to require is **noti.png**

I got this error

[image]

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the location of the image incorrectly. as you can see in the error: `the module .. could not be found`

To fix it, check the location of current file you are calling that image then go back to the exact location and call it. Also If you are using IDE they recommend you the location.

#### Update:

`require('../assets/images/noti.png'`

Comment: The file im working with Notification.js. which is in the components folder, the image noti.png is in images folder. I think I got the path right. Or didn't i?

Comment: you are right. I got the wrong path. it should be ../assets/image/noti.ong

Comment: any time my friend